# Read A File from FormData

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file, form-data

I'm running in a context of an Adobe Extension, using NodeJS.
My extension as a form with `FileInput` of video files.
I am trying to extract the audio of the file using `fmpeg` to save up on the upload time to my server.

Sadly, `ffmpeg` requires a `FileReadStream` or a `File Path` input in order to work.
but I'm just lost. I can't get the file that the user fills in the form in the needed format.

`fileInputElement.value` simply returns a FakePath (e.g. `C:/Fake/File.mp4`)
And I can't find any other way to actually get the file, into my Javascript code.

Do you have an idea?

Thank you so much in advance!